# Invalid controller configuration at Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-mvc-test, spring-web

I am new to Spring framework. I would to develop a simple web-app that displays a hello.jsp content based on url "/greeting.html". But now, it gives me 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the github repo for my project (this project was created under Eclipse STS): https://github.com/terancet/EventTracker

Here is my HelloController class

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");

        return "hello.jsp";
    }

}
```

Here is web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>


        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.pluralsight.WebConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is a project structure:

[image: project structure]

Comment: Could you replace `@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")` with `@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting.html")` and try?

Comment: what is the full url you are hitting?

Comment: My full url - http://localhost:8080/EvenTracker/greeting.html . I have replaced with the "/greeting.html" and still there is 404 error.

Comment: can you add your jsp controller call here

Comment: I have updated with the link to repo: https://github.com/terancet/EventTracker

Comment: Post your configuration.

Comment: Since you are using spring boot, it would ideally run under root. So trying hitting with `localhost:8080/greeting.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a log4j.xml or log4j.properties into the

> src/main/resources

folder (it will automatically be detected). **Then when you start up the server it will tell you exactly where the url mapping is for your controller via info log**. This is important not to only verify the mapping url but to make sure it is actually being mapped:

Also, in STS/Eclipse if you:

```
right click on the project -> click properties -> click select 'Web Project Settings'
```

[image]

by default that is where the url path is derived. So if the context-root value in there is: 'EventTracker' then your full url request will be (assuming a '.jsp' suffix is set as others have indicated in your resolver):

> http://localhost/EventTracker/greetings

Sample log4j.xml from 1 of my projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"> 

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
           <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p:%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss} %t %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="c:/tmp/my-app.log"/>
       <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
       <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="50"/>

       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p:%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss} %t %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.webflow">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger> 


    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </root>


</log4j:configuration>
```

log info:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/userManagement/getUser],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.assessme.com.entity.User org.assessme.com.controller.UserManagementController.data(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
```

Comment: Thank you for a hint (about log4j). I have made a simple output to a console and it complains me that there is no controller to request mapping at dispatcher. However, I have made an explicit mapping via @Request annotation. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your `WebConfig` you have the following

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return resolver;
}
```

Your controller is returning `hello.jp`. This is passed on the to `InternalResourceViewResolver` to be resolved to a view. It will create an path of **`/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp.jsp`** and next it forwards to this path.

First make your controller return `hello` instead of `hello.jsp`. Second create a `jsp` directory inside the `WEB-INF` directory and move your `hello.jsp` there. Third restart.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Made the corrections as you have suggested, but still though, I am receiving a 404 error while accessing the following url path: http://localhost:8080/EventTracker/greeting.html

Comment: How is your application deployed? As root i.e. `/` or `/EventTracker`. Also URLs are case sensitive... Also what you posted here doesn't match what you have in your repo, which is using spring boot... Next to that it is also using `forward:` instead of returning a view name. So not sure what you posted here but it doesn't match what you link to. (And preferably you should include everything in your question instead of letting people search through github for information).

Answer (score 0):

It could be typo in application name. Please try localhost:8080/Even**t**Tracker/greeting - EventTracker with Even**t**

And try to change url-pattern to /*

Comment: But, if I change to /* all get requests will be mapped to hello.jsp.

Comment: tried to do it and it didnt help. when I type the following url: http://localhost:8080/EventTracker/greeting.html the 404 error appears ...